# Stateful interaction for testing Express Apps

Tags: node.js, testing, express, mocha.js, supertest

I wrote a simple JSON api with express and I'm trying to use mocha to do some black-box testing. Throughly testing the API requires authenticating as different users, so each test for a specific feature is made of at least two requests: a login operation and one or more authenticated requests that test the actual feature.

I haven't found any library similar to `django.test.client` to simulate stateful interaction between an HTTP client and a server. Supertest seems to be popular, but it is very low-level compared to the django test client. This is how I would write a simple authenticated test with it (pardon my coffeescript):

```
it 'should return a 200 OK', (done) ->
  supertest(server.app)
    .post('/login')
    .send("username=xxx&password=pass")
    .end (err, res) ->
      res.should.have.status(200)
      supertest(server.app)
        .get('/api/users')
        .set('cookie', res.headers['set-cookie'][0])
        .expect(200, done)
```

Is this really the cleanest way to execute the interaction? Is there any library that would help me with asynchronicity (it's not like I am going to need anything but plain serialization of the tests in 99% of cases, callbacks are just confusing) and statefulness? Something that would go like this:

```
it 'should rock', (done) -> myCoolLibrary [
  ->
    @post '/login', {username: "xxx", password: "pass"}, (err, res) =>
      res.should.have.status 200
      @done()
  ,
  ->
    @get '/api/users', (err, res) =>
      res.should.have.status 200
      @done()
  ]
```

If nothing similar exists, I should write it myself :-)
The reliance on the context is because I am using too much ZappaJS these days, and thanks to CoffeeScript's fat arrow, it's not a bad idiom at all.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you could benefit from [zombiejs](http://zombie.labnotes.org/). It simulates a browser and keeps cookies and session data between requests.

It also gives you more powerful features such as allowing you to fill out forms and submit them, for example.

A typical test would look something like this:

```
var Browser = require('zombie')
  , browser = new Browser({site:'http://yoursite.com'});
describe('page',function(){
    before(function(done){
        browser.visit('/loginpage',done);
    });
    it('should return a 200 page',function(done){
        browser.fill('username','xxx');
        browser.fill('password','pass');
        //assuming your form points to /login
        browser.pressButton('button[type="submit"]'),function(){
            assert(browser.success); //status code is 2xx
        }).then(done,done); //call the done handler after promise is fulfilled
    });
    it('should rock',function(done){
        browser.visit('/api/users',function(){
            assert(browser.success);
        }).then(done,done);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

As a more general solution for making async code cleaner to read, check out async. https://github.com/caolan/async

async.serial would do just what you need, but I would particularly recommend async.auto, which allows you to link together various steps with their dependencies in a clear way.

Comment: An earlier revision of the post had something along the lines of "This looks a lot like async.series and it's not a coincidence". I should have left it in there :-) Obviously node.js is not missing any building blocks, but coming from a more monolithic framework I find it tedious to discover and learn 10 modules just to do something so simple. I ended up writing a very Zappa-specific implementation myself, I will post it here at some point.

Comment: The node ecosystem is kind of like Perl: there's more than one way to do it. You spend a lot of time evaluating potential module options.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing myself a small library that is pretty close to my "ideal" example in the question. It doesn't deserve its own package for now, so I just put it in a gist:

https://gist.github.com/BruceBerry/5485917

I could not get superagent and supertest to perform stateful interaction, so I just ditched them in favor of request. The main difference seems to be that you can't chain expects and you have to do all tests in the callback, but those look odd anyway if you are already using another testing library such as should.js